# C++ iterators - Deduce dimensionality

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm calculating the determinant of a matrix, the calculations and therefore a method is called depending on the dimensionality of the data, for example:

```
template<int X, int Y>
float determinant(X, Y, std::vector<Vector> &data)
{
    // Determine the dimensionality of matrix data (x and y) 
}
```

The problem that I am having is that in the class that calculates the PCA, which calls this function, only accepts an iterator:

```
class PCA { 

   public: 

      template<typename T> 
      PCA(T begin, T end)
      {
          // Determine the X and Y here
          float det = determinant(X, Y, ....); 
      }
};
```

Now I am wondering whether or not it is possible to deduce the `X` and `Y` from the iterator that has been passed through PCA, rather than passing in two integer values.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

EDIT:

Apologises, my question was not clear.

Basically, `typedef std::vector<double> Vector;` is used so therefore `std::vector<Vector> data;` would therefore be a vector of vectors.

I sample this doing the following:

`std::vector<Vector> data1 = { {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {8, 9} }; // 2x2` whereas when I want to add the following: `std::vector<Vector> data2 = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12} }; // 3x3` so obviously, when calculating the determinant there is a different calculation for this.

I want to deduce that data1 is a 2x2 and data2 3x3 from the function without having to specifically pass these values in.

Comment: You need to post that iterator's code if you want any help.

Comment: what is type X and Y here (why not just int?)? Who defines the Iterator? If you define the iterator, you could put typedef in the definition of the iterator, and do sth like determinant (T::DIMType1, T::DIMType2)

Comment: @Marco How do you mean the iterator's code? Sorry

Comment: Are you looking for 'std::iterator_traits' ?

Comment: I mean that we can't see the code where X and Y are, thus we can't help. That template parameter could be anything

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If all you have is the number of elements (from `end - begin`), then there's many dimensions that would fit, no? Unless the iterator is some special iterator that has access to the dimensions somehow?

Comment: @Cameron Hey, basically, there will either be a `2x2` or `3x3` sorry for the confusion regarding my question.

Comment: @user1326876: can you show sample usage, where you create a PCA from a pair of iterators, and we can see what dimensions you're talking about?  What is `Vector`?  Does the `std::vector<Vector>` represent a 2d array by itself, or is it one dimension while the `Vector` is the other dimension, or is each `Vector` a 2d array?  Or are there 3d arrays involved?

Comment: @MooingDuck I have updated my question, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @user1326876 I'm not sure how 8 elements can make up a 2x2 matrix.. but by the way you might (if you have all square matrices) count the number of elements with vector::size()

Comment: @user1326876 I'm still trying to figure out why you say a `vector` of 4 `Vector`s of 3 elements is "obviously" a 3x3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since vectors aren't fixed-size, they could be jagged. (Constrast this with, e.g. `std::array<>` or `T [N][M][L]`; you could deduce their ranks at compiletime).

Let's assume they're not: see it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbe4121ef644a3a0)**

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <deque>

template <typename V>
    std::deque<std::size_t> dims_of(V const& v) {
    return {};
}

template <typename T>
    std::deque<std::size_t> dims_of(std::vector<T> const& v)
{
    if (v.empty())
        return { 0 };
    else
    {
        auto dims = dims_of(v.front());
        dims.push_front(v.size());
        return dims;
    }
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int> > > const
        v(7, std::vector<std::vector<int> >(
            10, std::vector<int>(3, 0)
            )
         );

    for (auto dim : dims_of(v))
        std::cout << dim << " ";

}
```

Prints

```
7 10 3
```

Comment: I like this method, really, I do. My main concern is would this go into the class "PCA" or into the namespace "Determinant" ?

Comment: Both could do AFAICS. It's just a utility function really, so it could be in a `Determinant::details` namespace, e.g.

Comment: Just realised, I would not be able to pass these two a template argument would I? They are not constants

Comment: You can't deduce runtime information at compiletime. That's impossible. So as long a you are using vectors, there's no way. Unless you simply hardcode the dimensions some other way. Perhaps it is time for a SSCCE http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions/22762#22762

Comment: I'm just going to hard-code it, since there will ever only be 2 or 3 dimensions that this library can handle. Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 0):

What about deriving from PCA into class that holds X and Y

```
template<int X,int Y>
PCA_size : public PCA
{
      enum { Xv=X};
      enum { Yv=Y};

}
```

Then you can just recast existing PCA object into yours

```
 static_cast<PCA_size<3,5> >(PCA_instance);
```